# ¿Cómo generar pdfs a partir de un data frame segmentado?

Tags: python, pdf, report

Python: Cómo realizar múltiples informes en pdf a partir de un data frame que debe segmentar los datos por números de tiendas?

Tengo la siguiente base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo crear múltiples informes en PDF para cada una las tiendas, para eso debo agrupar las compras por cada una de las tiendas, ya que 1 tienda puede tener varios registros los cuales deben aparecer en un mismo informe. EL formato del informe es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora he podido segmentar el `dataframe`, creando tantos `dataframes` como tiendas haya con la información requerida.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas añadí una suma del total de las columnas IMPORTE y UN
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dando como resultado 28 `dataframes` agrupados por TIENDAS. (Ver imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por los momentos no pude avanzar mas, necesito saber como generar los múltiples PDF y como colocar el formato del informe tal como sale en la 2da imagen. Si alguien me puede echar una mano estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a SOes! Te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [Tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona el sitio y así de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular una pregunta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida.

Comment: Algunos usuarios pueden tener problemas para visualizar las imágenes, por eso es importante poner toda la información que sea un texto como texto/código. Ademas de que dificultas a los que te quieran ayudar ya que no pueden copiar parte de tu código para responderte.Por favor cambia las imágenes por textos!

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Dos cosas, • la primera, el código puedes colocarlo en texto?, eso ayudaría a la gente que te quiera dar mejoras de tu código o similar, además que en móviles la vista de imágenes es algo complicada.

• Segundo, y si creas una plantilla en Word y luego hacer Merge con estos datos y conviertes el word a PDF?, no es más sencillo?, o incluso, una plantilla en PDF; y solo le hacer merge a los datos, puedes usar cosas como `<nombre>` `<notafactura>` y cosa así para que busques y reemplaces el texto. Puede ser una idea ya que como indicas, ya tienes los datos respectivos para cada archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve una situacion similar. La solución fue llenar el informe en un excel y después exportarlo a pdf.

Necesitas tener una plantilla en excel en la que vas a escoger en qué celdas vas a poner tus datos variables.

Digamos que la fecha la pones en la celda 'E2' entonces llenas esto en tu excel plantilla yo use openpyxl.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('donde este tu plantilla')
ws = wb.active
ws['E2'].value = 'fecha'
```

Ya que llenas todos los datos de tu informe necesitas 'imprimir' a un pdf. Yo no encontre una libreria que hiciera todo entonces use win32com.client que te permite abrir y exportar a pdf. Aqui la funcion que uso:

```
def printToPDF(WB_PATH,PATH_TO_PDF):
    import win32com.client
    import pathlib
    from pywintypes import com_error

    # Path to original excel file
    WB_PATH = pathlib.Path(WB_PATH).absolute()
    # PDF path when saving
    PATH_TO_PDF = pathlib.Path(PATH_TO_PDF+'/REMISION.pdf').absolute()
    excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = False

    try:
        print('Start conversion to PDF')
        # Open
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(WB_PATH)

        # Specify the sheet you want to save by index. 1 is the first (leftmost) sheet.
        ws_index_list = [1]
        wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()
        # Save
        wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, PATH_TO_PDF.__str__())
    except com_error as e:
        print('failed.',e)
    else:
        print('Succeeded.')
    finally:
        excel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
        excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close()
        excel.Quit()
```

Comment: La primer linea de `finally` omite el cartel de "Desea guardar los cambios efectuados en....?"